# Passing command line arguments to classes

Tags: ruby

When developing large scale command line applications that are composed of multiple classes, which need to use options passed from the command line, how do you construct the code such that you can use those options?

I write code like this:

```
class DatabaseHandler
  def initialize(cmd_options = {})
    @cmd_options = cmd_options
  end

  def some_method
    puts @cmd_options[:cmd_parameter]
  end
end
```

which, seems tedious and unnecessary to me. What is the Ruby best practice for using command line option parameters in your project's classes?  Help appreciated.

Comment: Did you consider using [Thor](https://github.com/erikhuda/thor)? it does exactly what you're trying to do. It's used by many other popular ruby gems, among which Rails, for example.

Comment: @TamerShlash: Thor does not solve passing options into dependencies, which is what the question is about.

Comment: +1 for Thor. Usually the logic that parses the command line is separated from the logic that initializes the objects you use. What you would do is have a configuration class/object where you would validate and set the input passed via cmd line. When building objects you would selectively cherry-pick things that the object needs.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby classes are simply that: classes. Good OOD applies, even if it's a command line application. If you need custom behaviour, use dependency injection or configure it using arguments. You *may* share the command line options using global variables, but as always, that comes at a price: shadowing, increasing complexity to understand the collaborators of a class, difficulty finding the source of a data, etc.

I'd suggest using factory methods to parse the input and return the correct configuration to be passed to a class. If you want nice examples of dependency injection, watch some [Sandi Metz talks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9lv2lBq6x4A), she really knows her stuff.

Comment: What I am wondering though, is how applications like Vagrant pass the command line options to the program but still separate the code as they do.  Thank you for the link! I will definitely check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Command-line options are no different from any other kind of configuration; configuration is configuration, no matter where it came from. So, you deal with them the same way you deal with other configuration, e.g. using

- a global singleton
- [Dependency Injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) (which is what you are doing in your example)
- [the Reader Monad](http://tonymorris.github.io/blog/posts/configuration-without-the-bugs-and-gymnastics/)
- …

For example, for request parameters (which is probably the closest analog to command-line arguments in a Web context), Rails uses a global method named `params` which returns a `Hash`-like object mapping parameter names to arguments. So, that would be an example of a global singleton.